# Print from web application DYMO labelwriter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dymo

I wrote a CMS with PHP and i need to print with a dymo labelwriter 450 some labels.
I've all the information stored on a mysql database and i want to print every row in a single Label but can't figure out how to implement:
- the framework, a soon as i move the js framework folder it stop working.
- post data from mysql to javascript.
Anyone ?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot print directly from web to the printer, because of security issues in browsers.

but you can build a .pdf file with label dimension per page and then the user only need to select the right printer (only the first time) and push print over the pdf file.

if you want to do it automatically you can build a little c# console application that query the webserver every x seconds to a specified page that send the pdf to the console application that print it for you.

Comment: Dymo does provide a javascript SDK which allows you to print from a browser provided that the Dymo software is installed on your PC/Mac. There is next to no documentation about it however, what there is can be found here: http://developers.dymo.com/2014/03/24/javascript-library-1-2-6-now-available/

Comment: That developers link is now 404/Page not found.